# Can I transfer only a few things by using migration assistant?

Tags: macos, migration, migration-assistant

So, I just recently got an M1 MacBook. I'm currently typing this on a mid-2014 Intel core MacBook Pro that's running on Yosemite. I wanted to transfer all my files into the new MacBook, however, I realized that it would take way too long, and I have a lot of junk that  I don't want on my new MacBook.

Is there a way to transfer only specific things that I want through migration assistant? Mainly some downloaded music from iTunes and some folders, not too many things (though it would probably be a few GB's.) but I don't want everything.

Answer (score 4):

In the Mac Migration Assistant process, it will give you *some* options to select the types of data you can migrate over from your user account, such as music, documents, etc... but it's not going to give you a full list of all directories and files to pick from. [image: migration assistant]

[image: Folders expanded to migrate]

There's an article here that also discussed this topic: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/selecting-folders-with-migration-assistant.1743009/